# tableview row height is wrong in first row at first section before scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am generating tableView with cell consist of stackView. Everything is ok, but first row at first section have wrong height before scrolling. I am using `cell.selectionStyle = .none` and it selecting as .default in that wrong cell before scrolling. How to fix that?

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
  self.tableView.setNeedsLayout()
  self.tableView.layoutSubviews()
  self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

^is there in `viewDidLoad()`. It didn't affect

Also tried cell.layoutIfNeeded(), still nothing.

Cell height is UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: can you show the code where you setting the cell height?

Comment: you have to set the height of the cell in heightForRow at index based on the section and cell then you will get the cell height what you looking for

Comment: Are you using autolayout? If yes then you should use UITableViewAutomaticDimension for your row height and estimated row height. If you are not using Autolayout, you should calculate the heights manually.

Comment: Sorry, updated the question

Comment: There's not only height problem. It also didn't accept selectionStyle, so there's some other problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After learning about `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, i achieved that:

All multiline `UILabel`'s must have specified value before cell reusing. It can be easily done by giving `nil` or just blank string (`""`) value for every label.text in your cell class, in `awakeFromNib()` method.

Example:

```
class HeaderTeacherTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var multilineLabel: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        multilineLabel.text = nil
    }
}
```

By multiline label i mean `UILabel()` with 0 number of lines.